# A whole bunch of material design errors

Tags: java, android, android-studio, material-design

When I open my android project I get a whole lot of material design errors. I think I changed a setting for material design accidently, how can I go back...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your project settings and select the platform as Android 5.0 (API 21). In your manifest, change the `targetSdkVersion` to "21". The new Appcompat-v22 needs all projects to be compiled against API 21.

Comment: oops my mistake ... what I meant was version 22 of appcompat-v7  :):):)  Basically the post-Lollipop version of appcompat-v7.